# tensorflow.keras IDE auto-completion fails

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pycharm, tensorflow2.0

TensorFlow 2 quickstart for experts
https://tensorflow.google.cn/tutorials/quickstart/advanced

PyCharm cannot import tensorflow.keras

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras import Model
```

It's happening due to the way tensorflow initializes its submodules lazily in tensorflow/**init**.py:

```
_keras_module = "keras.api._v2.keras"
_keras = _LazyLoader("keras", globals(), _keras_module)
_module_dir = _module_util.get_parent_dir_for_name(_keras_module)
if _module_dir:
  _current_module.__path__ = [_module_dir] + _current_module.__path__
setattr(_current_module, "keras", _keras)
```

**solution 1:**
As a quick test on my local, I manually created a symlink under venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow by

```
ln -s ../keras/api/_v2/keras/ keras
```

(assuming you have tensorflow and keras pip package installed properly), and then the IDE can resolve the package level auto completion correctly.

**solution 2:**
change to

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D
from keras import Model
```

**solution 3:**

This will become the standard in the next release, keras 2.13.
The new `tf.keras` and `keras` namespaces are 100% identical.

reference

- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/56231
- https://twitter.com/fchollet/status/1639776922019454976?s=20
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-33034
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-34174
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-53599

is there any other perfect solution?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.